# how can i perfom computed columns in Oracle like in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

How  can I create the table like this with compound columns in oracle:

The table definition in SQL Server is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CCtestUsingSubstring] (
   [EmpNumb] INT NOT NULL, 
   [Designation] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
   [DOBirth] DATETIME NOT NULL, 
   [DORetirement] AS REPLACE([Designation],'E','O') )

insert into [CCtestUsingSubstring] values(1,'Developer',1/10/1992)

Select * from [CCtestUsingSubstring]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CCtestUsingSubstring] (
   [EmpNumb] INT NOT NULL, 
   [Designation] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
   [DOBirth] DATETIME NOT NULL, 
   [DORetirement] AS REPLACE([Designation],'E','O') )

insert into [CCtestUsingSubstring] values(1,'Developer',1/10/1992)

Select * from [CCtestUsingSubstring]
```

Comment: This is in SQL how can i perform the same thing in Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Oracle calls this "virtual column":

```
CREATE TABLE CCtestUsingSubstring (
   EmpNumb INT NOT NULL, 
   Designation VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
   DOBirth DATE NOT NULL, 
   DORetirement AS (REPLACE(Designation,'e','O')));

insert into CCtestUsingSubstring (EmpNumb, Designation, DOBirth) 
values(1,'Developer',date '1992-10-01');

Select * from CCtestUsingSubstring
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_tab_t AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
/
CREATE TABLE nested_table (id NUMBER, col1 my_tab_t)
       NESTED TABLE col1 STORE AS col1_tab;

INSERT INTO nested_table VALUES (1, my_tab_t('A'));
INSERT INTO nested_table VALUES (2, my_tab_t('B', 'C'));
INSERT INTO nested_table VALUES (3, my_tab_t('D', 'E', 'F'));
COMMIT;
```